# Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?

Tags: linux, node.js, command-line

How do you uninstall node.js using the cmd line in linux?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Edit: If you know which package manager was used to install, it is best to uninstall with the same package manager. Examples for `apt`, `make`, `yum` are in other answers.

This is a manual approach:

Running `which node` will return something like `/path/bin/node`.

Then run `cd /path`

This is all that is added by Node.JS.

```
rm -r bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node.1
```

Now the only thing I don't know about is npm and what it has installed. If you install npm again into a custom path that starts off empty, then you can see what it adds and then you will be able to make a list for npm similar to the above list I made for node.

Comment: You must know that Nodejs has npm as well if you do this you will end up with a mess to unistall npm or aany other package you install using it

Comment: Some people might need to run `which nodejs` as I did in Ubuntu

Comment: I did the same, now when I do `node -v` it shows nothing but the file and folder remains there under folder **node**. So its not removed fully!!

Comment: @Jubair You cannot remove npm if you've already removed node, because npm needs node to run.

Comment: I know but the above solution only removes node, leaving the npm packages intact.  so I'd remove npm first then the node files.  Another way, in addition to the above rm command, doing this should remove the npm files `rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*`

Comment: If you still have source stored somewhere when you install this version.
You can do `cd path/to/the/source`, then `sudo make uninstall`.

Comment: Removing a folder is, at least, dangerous and it doesn't guarantee the clean removal of a product.  I would recommend avoiding applying this answer unless you have removed the product first and you find it leaves some files behind.  You can remove the product cleanly by using the corresponding command as it has been explained in other answers of this thread.

Comment: @LuckyBrain, Edited 

Comment: I guess this manual removal process is only applicable if one has downloaded an archived format of a nodejs version, then extracted it somewhere, with the bin directory appended to the PATH variable. On the other hand, if someone else have installed node via a package manager, then it must have certainly outspread node internals at the respective HFS directories. Nvm and manual installation are the ones that install node versions in consolidated confinement.

Comment: Why does this answer have so many votes, its terrible.

Comment: i followed this answer so i  stuck with a half removed node and npm. fortunately i could fix it by installing a newer version of the previous one. so do not do this if you have node js installed and working.

Answer (score 437):

For **Ubuntu 12.04**:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

This will uninstall `nodejs` as well as `npm`.

Comment: now these are the kind of answers i like... simple and to the point. thanks a bunch! worked like a charm for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This didn't remove the `.nmp` directory in my home directory `~`. I removed it myself. Are there any other files or directories like that I need to remove to completely remove node and npm?

Comment: I had to run sudo apt-get -f install before running the remove command. Afterwards, it was removed successfully.

Comment: Worked for me on Lubunto 16.04. Woot!

Comment: Works on Ubuntu16.04.6 LTS too

Comment: Note to users new to Linux: replace 'apt-get' in the above command with 'dnf' if you are using Fedora/ Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Comment: Insteresting... it seems I can uninstall apt and npm versions of npm independently (as long as nodejs is installed). `apt remove npm` uninstalled the deb pkg, but kept the update I made to npm using itself. To remove that I also had to do `npm un -g npm` with nodejs pkg installed.

Comment: To reinstall:
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install nodejs npm`

Comment: It also works in Debian distribution

Answer (score 90):

If you installed from source, you can issue the following command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

If you followed the instructions on https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki to install to your $HOME/local/node, then you have to type the following before the line above:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
```

Comment: will that remove npm and its installs?

Comment: Probably not. You are better off running `npm uninstall npm` to uninstall npm prior to uninstalling node.

Comment: thats really odd it seemed to uninstall a bunch of files said it uninstalled but when i type node it still enters node mode...i rebooted the server to in case it was in ram

Comment: Hmm... do you have to specify an installation prefix, to uninstall a version in a custom place such as your local home directory?

Comment: If you'd removed sources and you have a fresh one, you need to run `./configure` then `sudo make uninstall`. if you didn't specify `--prefix`  you don't need `--prefix` now

Answer (score 58):

Sorry the answer of George Bailey does work very fine when you
want absolutely remove the node from your machine.

This answer is referred from : @tedeh
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/486

If you wanna install a new version of node you have to use the code below

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum
sudo yum remove -y nodejs
sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource*
sudo yum clean all
```

And add new nodejs version to "yum" an new version of node

```
#using this command for Node version 8
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -

#using this command for Node version 10
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
```

Install nodejs

```
sudo yum -y install nodejs
```

I hope it gonna help you guy!!!

Comment: This works! Forgotten I'd installed it with yum. `yum list installed | grep nodejs` to check. +1

Comment: confirmed to be good on removing node 10, and installing node 12 on centos 7

Comment: You saved my day! :)

Comment: i tried with running this curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash - and sudo yum -y install nodejs commands, but the installed version was v6.17.1 it was not 12

Answer (score 33):

To uninstall node I followed the accepted answer by @George, as I no longer have the sources, but before doing so I ran:

```
sudo npm rm npm -g
```

That seemed to get rid of npm from the system directories such as `/usr/bin/npm` and `/usr/lib/npm`. I got the command from [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/22051). I then found a `~/.npm` directory, which I deleted manually. Honestly I don't know if every trace of npm has been removed, but I can't find anything else.

Answer (score 33):

If you installed node using `curl` + `yum`:

```
sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
sudo yum -y install nodejs
```

Then you can remove it using `yum`:

```
sudo yum remove nodejs
```

Note that using the `curl` script causes the wrong version of node to be installed. [There is a bug](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/340) that causes `node` v6.7 to be installed instead of v4.x intended by the path `(../setup_4.x)` used in the `curl` script.

Answer (score 18):

This is better to remove NodeJS and its modules manually because installation leaves a lot of files, links and modules behind and later it create problems while we reconfigure another version of NodeJS and its modules.
Run the following commands.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules 


sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*     
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*         
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
```

and this done.

A step by step guide with commands is at http://amcositsupport.blogspot.in/2016/07/to-completely-uninstall-node-js-from.html

This helped me resolve my problem.

Comment: This helped remove an older, orphaned version of npm. Helpful to also run `hash -r` afterwards.

Answer (score 11):

I think Manoj Gupta had the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13005355/5517982) from what I'm seeing. However, the remove command doesn't get rid of any configuration folders or files that may be leftover. Use:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
```

The purge command should remove the package and then clean up any configuration files. (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove) question for more info on the difference between purge and remove). The auto-remove flag will do the same for packages that were installed by NodeJS.

See the accepted answer on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/786019/1084637) question for a better explanation.

Although don't forget to handle NPM! Josh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7985097/5517982) covers that.

Comment: Is apt-get Linux only?

Answer (score 8):

The answer of George Bailey works fine.
I would just add the following flags and use sudo if needed:

```
 sudo rm -rf bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node
```

Comment: I found an official `rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*` removal command @ [https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm), I'm not sure if it's logically equivalent to your command, I'll try it though (it might require a `sudo`, too).

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04 *sudo apt-get remove nodejs* helps me to sort out this problem.

Comment: @BigRich I'm not quite sure what you mean by "logically", but your bygone reference, expands to totally different directories. He should've explicitly prefixed the directories with a forward slash too or directory of some kind.

Comment: @polendina, been 7 years, instead of 'logically' I probably meant simply 'not exactly the same as'. 

As you state, my command, directly from NPMJS themselves, expands to a different set of directory locations, for a NodeJS installation relative to `/usr/local`. 

I believe that the OP, and others of a technical standard sufficient to consider the installation and subsequent removal of NodeJS from their systems, would in fact be able to 'tweak' the command I offered in good faith, to the particular needs and layout of their own system(s), as to not use it 'blindly' - I offered a 'hint'.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to just update node, there's a neat updater too

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

to use,

> git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
>
> source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
>
> nvm install v0.4.1

Answer (score 5):

I think this works, at least partially (have not investigated):

`nvm uninstall <VERSION_TO_UNINSTALL>`

eg:

`nvm uninstall 4.4.5`

Answer (score 5):

If you have yum you could do:

`yum remove nodesource-release* nodejs`

`yum clean all`

And after that check if its deleted:

`rpm -qa 'node|npm'`

Answer (score 4):

after installing using the "ROCK-SOLID NODE.JS PLATFORM ON UBUNTU" script, i get this output. Which tells you how to uninstall nodejs.

> Done. The new package has been installed and saved to
>
> /tmp/node-install/node-v0.8.19/nodejs_0.8.19-1_i386.deb
>
> You can remove it from your system anytime using:
>
> ```
>   dpkg -r nodejs
> ```

Comment: Worked with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as well

Answer (score 4):

Best way to go around this is to do it right from the BEGINNING:

**INSTALL [BREW](http://brew.sh/linuxbrew/)**

```
#HERE IS HOW: PASTE IN TERMINAL

sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

Then at the end of your .bashrc file(In your home directory press Ctrl + H)

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Then restart terminal so the modification to .bashrc are reloaded

**TO INSTALL NODE**

```
brew install node
```

**TO CHECK VERSION**

```
node -v
npm -v
```

**TO UPDATE NODE**

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
```

**TO UNINSTALL NODE**

```
brew uninstall node
```

Comment: Follow the first steps to install it. Then added to the path

Comment: Brew as a terminal command can be used in OSX or Linux based systems. The only difference between the two system is that brew the original is for OSX and LinuxBrew is a version of it for Linux. The one I'm talking here is LinuxBrew. So once more if you follow the instructions you could use it in Linux based systems. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about installing an additional package manager that might cause conflict by overwriting the same directories, or outright be nullified by its low priority in its binaries invocation, behind the formerly dangling node/npm versions. Anyways, OP is asking for explicit removal solution, not a workaround!

Answer (score 1):

To Remove nodejs installed in centos 8:
From your home directory, run the below command

```
sudo yum remove nodejs
```

Enter y to confirm your command

Comment: you do not need to the home directory FYI. And try to elaborate a bit further to make your answer more explanatory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to apt or yum removal, clean any residual files to avoid conflicts if you ever install a new version:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d 
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm 
sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp 
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node 
sudo rm -rf opt/local/include/node 
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules  
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
```

Answer (score 1):

For Centos 7 and 8

### Remove NodeJS

```bash
sudo yum remove -y nodejs
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum
sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource*
sudo yum clean all
```

### Remove residual files

```bash
whereis node
sudo rm -rfv /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz
sudo rm -rfv /usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/share/man/man1/npm.1.gz
sudo rm -rfv /usr/local/bin/npx
sudo rm -rfv /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rfv /usr/local/include/node*
sudo rm -rfv /usr/lib/node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these files. No need to do anything else.

```
rm -rf ~/.nvm
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf ~/.bower
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Debian 11:

```
$ sudo apt remove nodejs
```

For my case, I wanted to remove both `nodejs` and `npm`:

```
$ sudo apt remove nodejs npm
```

Answer (score 0):

for Linux Debian I wanted to remove node , npm and nvm so I did

`nvm uninstall v14.21.3`. Do same for each version
and do `nvm deactivate` and then uninstall the currently used version

in `/home/user` directory (that is where nvm was installed for me)

`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm -rf .npm`

`rm -rf .npmrc` ( you can leave this but I removed it)

`rm -rf .nvm`

`sudo nano .bashrc` and then remove these lines

```
  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```