# How can I find an old version of node?

Tags: macos, node.js

I've installed a new version of node via n but the version that runs is still a old one. I don't know where I installed the old version, how can I go find it and uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which node from the command line if Unix/OSX.  'where node' in Windows.

Comment: OP wants to find his old version, not download it.

Comment: @Blender: And `which node` should tell him where this old version is installed at...

Comment: it would be /usr/bin/node.  usr/bin would be relative to your current working directory.

Comment: Thanks Richard, very helpful! Running 0.6.6 now!

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
which node
```

And see where the executable is.

Comment: What is proper procedure to uninstall it once I know this information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line