# How can i reinstall my node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Yesterday, i try to uninstall node.js from my ubuntu. But i can uninstall only npm from my computer, surely. Now i want to uninstall node.js from my ubuntu(12.04) and install again. Firstly, please let me know about uninstalling node.js after I'll install it again.

I'm waiting..

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask that quesiton

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line) might help. It's not for ubuntu specifically, but it shows how to unintall node on linux.

Comment: after i run sudo apt-get remove nodejs, i'm typing node via terminal and it's running still.

Comment: @YabMarket Sorry. But, why the comment about `apt-get remove`? This answer makes no mention of `apt-get`. The linked post explains how to just `rm` the installation. And, since `apt-get` is apparently failing, you'll probably have to `rm` the files yourself.