# how to delete node on linux mint 13?

Tags: linux, node.js

Node will not delete on Linux Mint 13.

see the video here
http://youtu.be/tV8HhS1xw2g
and
here
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8DNvv3iFdI

I installed via git but node failed to run see https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5/issues/73 for the tests I ran to try to get node to play nice.

so I uninstalled the git version and installed the Ubuntu v. apt-get install node
    $ which node
    /usr/local/bin/node

```
$ node --version
v0.5.11-pre
```

That node didn't work either... but I can't delete node now!

```
$ sudo apt-get remove node
[sudo] password for dennis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package node is not installed, so not removed
```

It's not deleting but the system still sees it.

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

I tried the advice found on: [Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line) but that didn't work either.

```
$./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node sudo make uninstall
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
dennis@64maya /usr/local/src/ipython/examples/notebooks $ sudo ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node sudo make uninstall
sudo: ./configure: command not found
```

Node is still installed:

```
$ node --version
v0.5.11-pre

$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node

$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ls
apt               ipcluster3     iplogger3  irunner3       pycolor
easy_install      ipcontroller   iptest     mint-md5sum    pycolor3
easy_install-3.2  ipcontroller3  iptest3    node           pygmentize
f2py3.2           ipengine       ipython    node-waf       search
highlight         ipengine3      ipython3   nosetests      yelp
ipcluster         iplogger       irunner    nosetests-3.2  zim
```

I tried dpkg... no joy.

```
$ dpkg -r node
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
dennis@64maya /usr/local/bin $ sudo dpkg -r node
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching node
dennis@64maya /usr/local/bin $ which node
/usr/local/bin/node

dennis@64maya /usr/local/bin $ node --version
v0.5.11-pre
```

How to delete all remnants of node so that I can eventually try to install it again?

Thank you
Dennis

Comment: Do you still have the old directory from where you `./configure`d and `make install`ed `node`? If you do, just `cd` into it and try running `sudo make uninstall`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line)

Comment: @n.m. If you read above and watch the videos, I did all of the things mentioned in  Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line. That's why I posted specifically here AND because my Q over at  Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line was deleted by admin.

Comment: @Blender I ran sudo make uninstall but the files and dirs are still there... shouldn't they all be gone after uninstalling? https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B19mmCKTPBRYTk1fWXdZclBZbWc/edit?usp=sharing and here's the video: http://youtu.be/yOZ3EE7yFMw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to. Just download again and

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node
cd node
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

You will then overwrite all files from previous installation, since you keep `--prefix=/usr/local` the same, then the installation procedure should overwrite all files into the same relative file path, following `/usr/local`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many thanks Marcel. Your instructions worked just fine! thank you! Here's the video: http://youtu.be/cUxM3R8JqEo

Comment: although I'm not a linux mint user, nor debian or ubuntu, I suspect there is a fundamental problem with the package you've tried to install. I did some research about dpkg troubleshooting, but with no luck... then this idea come to mind, and voi la.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the source from git again so that you can run the `./configure` script and make script from within the source directory. The problem there too is that you used the wrong prefix, I think. Given the output from your `which` command which shows `node` is installed in `/usr/local/bin/node`, I think your `--prefix` is `/usr/local/`. So try:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local && sudo make uninstall
```

From within the source directory.