# Cloud9 on Raspberry Pi, Unable to save files

Tags: node.js, save, raspberry-pi, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to get the cloud9 local server working on my Raspberry Pi(512mb model B, running raspbian).

I followed this installation guide:
http://www.slickstreamer.info/2013/02/how-to-install-cloud-9-on-raspberry-pi.html

After this installation everything appeared to be working properly, I can start the server with the following command:
    ~/cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0 -w ~/Documents/www/workspace/

when I start the server all the files in the workspace are displayed properly and I can view, duplicate, delete, and create files remotely no problem. But when I edit an existing file and try to save it remotely a little spinning wheel pops up on the tab of the file I'm saving and it continues to spin endlessly.

When I start the server a warning pops up saying: 'path.existsSync is now called `fs.existsSync`.' I'm not sure if that is relevant or not.

I found another thread somewhere saying that I should go through cloud9/configs/default.js and replace any instance of localhost with 0.0.0.0. I tried that, but it didn't fix my problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to get cloud9 saving files properly?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You just gave me my next project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fully removed cloud9 and node(followed these directions to remove node: [Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line)), and then did a clean install following these directions: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=30265. In addition to those commands I also had to run the following:

```
sudo npm install formidable

sudo npm install gnu-tools

sudo npm install xmldom
```

after that I was able to start the cloud9 server without issue, and now I'm able to save files.

thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

There were several complains about [IDE file saving hangs](http://support.c9.io/entries/21068062-IDE-File-Saving-hangs-) on cloud9 support. At the bottom of the page there is a solution you can try.

Comment: I tried the fixes on that page, but they didn't work for me. Thanks for trying though, I hadn't seen that page.