# Express doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, npm

I'm new with nodejs and trying to learn it. I have installed node framework express as global module by command:

```
$ sudo npm install express -g
```

This works correctly and I have it in `/usr/lib/node_modules`. Then I'm creating a new project on express:

```
 $ express app
```

But this doesn't create project folder and does not return any error code, clear node code works fine. Anybody knows how to detect and fix this error?

Comment: What's your current path when you're running `$ express app`? (The result of `$ pwd`)

Comment: OK, and what's the output from `$ npm -g ls | grep express`?

Comment: This one express@3.4.6

Comment: Peculiar! Can you run just `express` at the command line? Are you even able to execute it at all?

Comment: yes looks works, but before I have reinstall node. So now I can create app with express. But anyway thank you for your help good man!;-)

Comment: Ah, yep. I've had lots of grief with dependencies, reinstalling Node is always the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to try is if the plugin is installed:

`$ npm -g ls | grep express`

If nothing is returned, try reinstalling it.

Since in this case it was still installed, the next solution was to reinstall Node entirely.

There is a great post on cleaning up Node installations here: [Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line)

Answer (score 37):

found it. the npm package is actually named express-generator

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

you can then use

```
express mytestapp
```

that results in :

```
olivier@****:~/workspace$ express mytestapp

create : mytestapp
create : mytestapp/package.json
create : mytestapp/app.js
create : mytestapp/public
create : mytestapp/public/javascripts
create : mytestapp/public/stylesheets
create : mytestapp/public/stylesheets/style.css
create : mytestapp/routes
create : mytestapp/routes/index.js
create : mytestapp/routes/users.js
create : mytestapp/views
create : mytestapp/views/index.jade
create : mytestapp/views/layout.jade
create : mytestapp/views/error.jade
create : mytestapp/bin
create : mytestapp/bin/www
create : mytestapp/public/images

install dependencies:
 $ cd mytestapp && npm install

run the app:
 $ DEBUG=my-application ./bin/www
```

Cheers !
Olivier

Source : http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable

Comment: You're my hero! I've been looking for a solution for awhile and finally found this.

Comment: That was the problem in my case. Thank you very much

Answer (score 23):

For me the solution was simply to install the nodejs-legacy package:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to get mine to work and make sure everything was working ok on Ubuntu 12.04 running Node 0.8.21 and Express 3.2.0.

First install express

```
sudo npm install –g express
```

Now check that express is working by querying it for the version:

```
express -V
```

Now I went and created an express app:

```
cd /usr/lib/node_modules
sudo express -s -e expressTestApp
```

The following was output:

```
create : expressTestApp
create : expressTestApp/package.json
create : expressTestApp/app.js
create : expressTestApp/public
create : expressTestApp/public/javascripts
create : expressTestApp/public/images
create : expressTestApp/public/stylesheets
create : expressTestApp/public/stylesheets/style.css
create : expressTestApp/routes
create : expressTestApp/routes/index.js
create : expressTestApp/routes/user.js
create : expressTestApp/views
create : expressTestApp/views/index.ejs

install dependencies:
 $ cd expressTestApp && npm install

run the app:
 $ node app
```

So, following the instructions it gave me, I ran the following two commands in sequence:

```
cd expressTestApp
sudo npm install
```

After just a minute it finished and I was able to open /urs/lib/node_modules/app.js and work with it.  Also, running node app like it said in the instructions during the express module creation worked as well.

From a previous comment, it looks like you might have fixed it by reinstalling node, but I still hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `sudo express app` might do the trick? (I see you're executing in `/var/www`, which generally is off limits from regular users?)

Comment: He fixed the problem by reinstalling Node ;)

Answer (score 0):

As of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the problem occurs when express is installed globally. To fix this, make sure you install express to your working directory even if you have installed globally.
 Use

`sudo npm i express-generator --save`

to save it to your working directory in every project you do.

Had this problem and fixed it easily, without having to reinstall nodejs or any other dependency.