# Why nodejs command line always install an old version?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu, npm, ionic-framework

My questions are

Whenever i tried to install nodejs using command line

```
# apt-get install nodejs
```

it installs the older version (in my case it installed 0.10.x),where as the current version till date is `4.1.2` .Why this command do not gives me a latest version.Is there any other way to install the latest version though i tried using `nvm`.

I checked the installed versions

```
node -v && npm -v && cordova -v
v0.12.7
3.3.5
5.3.3
```

It seems node v0.12.7 is installed in my system but when i am trying to install `ionic`

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

i am finding the error

```
    npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} 

(current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"3.3.5"})
```

even my current version is greater then the required version why its throwing me an error,do it strict with the specific version.

Answer (score 3):

Do not make use of `apt get`, there is no harm in installing node using platform specific tools but it is better to make use of `nvm` which is consistent among all platforms.

Make sure to uninstall the current version of node [this post can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line).

Next follow these steps.

1. Go to https://github.com/creationix/nvm
2. Use curl to install nvm `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.28.0/install.sh | bash`
3. Source your profile `source ~/.profile`
4. Install NodeJs `nvm install v4.1.0`
5. Alias installed version to default `nvm alias default v4.1.0`
6. Set aliased version as the final node version `nvm use default`
7. `node -v` will result in `v4.1.0`

In your case you may have to install version `0.10.x`, you can also do `nvm ls-remote` to list available versions for download.

Comment: Upgrading node version works fine for me,but still why i am getting a warning while installing ionic,why i need v0.10.x even when i am having version greater than that,won't it support the older versions dependents?

Comment: No this is not how npm works. I module defines it's dependencies on certain versions on node and npm will throw warning no matter whether you can the greatest version or not. It is quite possible that new version may have removed something that package is dependent upon. So it's npm responsibility to warn you about same

Answer (score -1):

it's warning not an error so don't worry and if you want to install ionic platform then use bellow commands and still you face any problem then message me.

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Comment: why i am getting a warning while installing ionic,why i need v0.10.x even when i am having version greater than that(4.1.0),won't it support the older versions dependents?