# Updating to Node 4.x in linux(ubuntu) fails with no error and stays with v0.10

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, npm, react-native

I have come across ReactJS and React Native. ReactJS is brilliant, super fast and works fine on Node v0.10. But, React Native needs v4.x as a prerequisite.
So, when I run any react-native command, it fails and says Node 4 is required.

I have tried several times and many ways to update Node, but, have failed.

First followed [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall) -

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I ended up with the following message-

```
root@purvotara:/# apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then, there was [Manual Installation](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debmanual) way of installing.

```
add-apt-repository -y -r ppa:chris-lea/node.js
rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chris-lea-node_js-*.list
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node/dists/trusty/Release main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node/dists/trusty/Release main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs
```

Still, ended up with -

```
nodejs is already the newest version.
```

I tried to **purge** and **auto-remove** my current v0.10 node and tried to freshly install, not sure if its still picking the install from the cache, but, v0.10 got installed.

Also followed [linoxide](http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/setup-node-js-4-0-ubuntu-14-04-15-04/) article on the same. A **.configure** and **make install** didn't seem to work as well.

**What am I doing wrong? I am stuck for hours.**

Went over several other links to resolve other issues(they are resolved now)-

[Uninstalling node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line)

[Failed to fetch Trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539409/failed-to-fetch-trusty)

Comment: So which version `node --version` is showing now?

Comment: It shows v0.10 when I do node -v

Comment: Have to tried installing different version using `NVM`?

Comment: When I execute the CURL command and run scripts, it fetches all content w.r.t 4.x, but, later, when I do an INSTALL, it says, its already upto date and version would be 0.10

Comment: @Manwal No I haven't tried NVM. I am not sure, but, read it somewhere it was used earlier(than npm) and not sure. Please correct me if I am wrong and guide me to the solution.

Comment: Actually you can install `NVM` and switch version of node anytime. This link may help you to download https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps

Comment: Oh! I wasn't aware of it. I will check it and update soon.

Comment: WOW! That was the solution! Classy! NVM got things working for me. Thanks a lot @Manwal .

Comment: Great that also helped me one. Enjoy node. That's why its full form is `Node Version Manager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Holger This was the result of using 'n'.
I have added this as an answer, as I want to bring more clarity in the code and solution itself.

Still facing the same problem.
I installed 4.2.1, but, v0.10 is being shown.

```
root@purvotara:/# n 4.2.1

 install : node-v4.2.1
   mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/4.2.1
   fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
 installed : v4.2.1

root@purvotara:/# n
root@purvotara:/# node -v
v0.10.25
```

---

I used NVM and the issue is solved.

Comment: mmmh, you might try to uninstall the original packages... `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`... i'm not sure it helps though

Comment: Yes. I will try it out! This 'n' looks clean. I will further investigate and get it working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use n. `npm install -g n`
then you can switch to any version of node using a command like this `n v4.1.2`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

n uses /usr/local/bin/node for n to work properly on debian based systems, create a symlink to point to this directory.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: This looks interesting! I will try it out and update the post soon.

Comment: Still facing the same problem.
I installed 4.2.1, but, v0.10 is being shown. Updated as a part of answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score -2):

You can Do it Two ways.  First try second step It must work for you.

1  Uninstall First version and Reinstall Other one `4.1.2` is latest as per my knowledge.

2   [Click Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)   Follow steps.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.16.1/install.sh | sh
source ~/.profile
nvm ls-remote
nvm install 4.*.*   // Latest version choose here
nvm use 4.*.*    // Latest version also here
node -v   // Check your version
```

Comment: I need node 4.x to be installed. Not Node 0.11. As I said earlier. I uninstalled node and reinstalled it. That is not giving the latest version.

Comment: when through command `nvm ls-remote`  than list out latest version of node JS. You can pass `nvm install 4.*.*` & `nvm use 4.*.*`

Comment: As per my knowledge `v4.2.1 ` is latest .

Comment: Yes. Thanks :) I updated to v4.2.1 and got it working.