# "Unable to find node js" message after completely removing it from Linux Mint

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, service, uninstallation, linux-mint

I've installed nodejs on Linux Mint and then completely removed it using these instructions:

[Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line)
[Completly uninstall nodejs, npm and node in ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/completly-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04)

After that when I tried to start a service using "service foo start", the following message appear:
"Unable to find node js install"

What shall i do? I don't want to have nodejs on this machine anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

How did you install it? If you have installed it using apt-get. 
You can use `apt-get purge nodejs` to remove the package and associated configuration files.