# Cannot update Node in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I installed Node.js on my Ubuntu machine. I typed `node` but it didn't work. I typed `nodejs` and it worked. When I asked for the version, `node -v` didn't work but `nodejs --version` worked, it gives me "v0.10.25."

I updated Node from https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs by using the commands
`sudo npm cache clean -f`,
`sudo npm install -g n`, and
`sudo n stable`.

Still it's not working. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest uninstall previous version and install your desired version from scratch.

**To uninstall old version:**

Run this command in your terminal:

```
lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom | while read f; do  sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
```

**To install new version:**

You can download both LTS and Beta version from the official site of [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

But the best way would be using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). This would help you install and use  multiple version of node on a single machine.

You can also use [n](https://github.com/tj/n). Which is similar to NVM but it's lightweight.

Comment: lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom | while read f; do  sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done     IT's showing command not found

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you are running a ubuntu machine.

This may help you uninstalling node - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line

Comment: Not correct. When I run it says lsbom: command not found

Answer (score 1):

try these simple commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash - 
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

- first you remove the previous nodejs version
- then download the latest 12.* nodejs version
- install the new version nodejs

sources:
https://vitux.com/how-to-uninstall-programs-from-your-ubuntu-system/
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

Answer (score 1):

I ran `npm cache clean -f` and `npm install -g n` like you did. After running `sudo n stable`, I typed in `PATH=$PATH` as they recommended me to and it worked. Typing `node -v` verified the update.

Comment: This was the solution I was searching for, works perfectly without long steps or setups.

Answer (score 0):

To update nodejs version in Linux using nvm(you can also use n to update nodejs version)

step 1: use wget to install nvm. Check it's official documentation for the latest version

wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash

Step 2: Check if installation is successful

command -v nvm

Step 3:download and update to the latest Node.js version. This will install the latest version of node. Check nodejs for the recommended versio to install

nvm install node

N.B To Upgrade a different version

nvm install version-number

example: nvm install 14.17.6

restart/close and open the terminal(optional) and check your node version

node -v

source: https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/update-node-js/