# Ubuntu: Node will not update to latest version

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, nvm

I have an issue on my Ubuntu VM. I have tried several methods of updating to the latest Nodejs version (both LTS and Current), but running `node --version` still shows v4.8.4.

I have tried using both `n` and `nvm` to update, as well as manually downloading and building. No matter what, v4.8.4 seems to be the only version running.

If I run `which node` I get `~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/node`. This looks correct, but `node --version` is still v4.8.4.

How can I fix this?

Comment: dupe question https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

Comment: Thank you @ScottStensland! That askubuntu link solved my problem. I needed to run `sudo ln -sf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you everyone for trying to help. The link @ScottStensland provided above (https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version) solved the issue for me. I needed a link!

`sudo ln -sf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs`

Answer (score 4):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Only this one is working the rest of the methods are not useful for the node

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04 its works:

Edit or create the file :nodesource.list

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

Insert this text:

> deb     https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic main
>
> deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic main

Run these commands:

```
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -


sudo sh -c "echo deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x cosmic main /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Check if it was updated

`nodejs -v`

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you have already tried - "I have tried several methods" isn't enough information for me to help you. But I will give it a try ;-)

You should know which Ubuntu version your virtual mashine offers. Just type in your terminal: `lsb_release -a`

Now you are free to follow the instructions from:

- [How can I update my nodeJS to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)
- or: [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

  - If you decide to do a fresh install you should uninstall it at first - have a look at: [Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line)

Comment: Your right. I wasn't very specific. I am running Ubuntu 17.04. The top two links you provided were both some of the methods I tried. Looks like I may need to do a delete and reinstall. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your cache and re-installing using a clean version?

Using Command Line/Terminal:

```
    sudo npm cache clean -f
    sudo npm install -g n  
    sudo n 0.8.11  
    sudo n stable
    node -v
```

node -v will check for the current version of node.js installed on your system.

In addition you can try installing globally using:

```
    npm install npm@latest -g
```

Or manage your NPM versioning using at https://github.com/creationix/nvm:

```
    nvm use system
    nvm run system --version
    nvm install node
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried all of these suggestions. Thank you. The `n` commands did not seem to do anything, neither did `npm install npm@latest -g`. `nvm install node` did update the version I have at `~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node` (the location `which node` returns), but `node -v` still returns v4.8.4

Comment: My pleasure. The final nvm sequencing worked for me when I was experiencing this problem. It was temporary and ultimately returned to the outdated version, however it did update it briefly.